# What is the error the code: getting invalid syntax in time method

Tags: python, python-3.x, delay, python-3.6, timedelay

```
#multiplication table with time delay
import time

num=int(input("Enter the value for which you want the multiplication table for:"))

print("The table will be as:\n")
for i in range(1,11):
    {
        print(num,"x",i,"=",num*i,"\n")
        time.sleep(3)
    }

print("The table is completed")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

In this code when compiler comes to this statement

```
time.sleep(3)
```

it shows **invalid syntax** error. What is error in this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is complaining about the `{}`s. In Python, they do not define a block, they define a dictionary. Thus, what you have inside the `{}`s is expected to be a dictionary literal, but that is not what you have. You probably want:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(num, "x", i, "=", num * i, "\n")
    time.sleep(3)
```

(Note, indentation is defining the block.)